# How to define summation type equation as constraints in Python optimization

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I was trying to solve a optimization problem using scipy package of python. But i don't know how to represent summation type equation as constraints and how to pass those constraint as argumnet to minimize function.

The equation is the following :

> > ∑ (Xrij + Xrji) - Yri >= 0,∀r,i
> >
> > j∈V
> >
> > For r=2, V=5 and i=5 
> >     I expanded the equation And defined every equation as separate constraint.

x[1][1][1]+ x[1][1][1]+ x[1][1][2]+ x[1][2][1]+ x[1][1][3]+ x[1][3][1]+ x[1][1][4]+ x[1][4][1]+ x[1][1][5]+ x[1][5][1] - y[1][1] >= 0

x[1][2][1]+ x[1][1][2]+ x[1][2][2]+ x[1][2][2]+ x[1][2][3]+ x[1][3][2]+ x[1][2][4]+ x[1][4][2]+ x[1][2][5]+ x[1][5][2] - y[1][2] >= 0

x[1][3][1]+ x[1][1][3]+ x[1][3][2]+ x[1][2][3]+ x[1][3][3]+ x[1][3][3]+ x[1][3][4]+ x[1][4][3]+ x[1][3][5]+ x[1][5][3] - y[1][3] >= 0

x[1][4][1]+ x[1][1][4]+ x[1][4][2]+ x[1][2][4]+ x[1][4][3]+ x[1][3][4]+ x[1][4][4]+ x[1][4][4]+ x[1][4][5]+ x[1][5][4] - y[1][4] >= 0

x[1][5][1]+ x[1][1][5]+ x[1][5][2]+ x[1][2][5]+ x[1][5][3]+ x[1][3][5]+ x[1][5][4]+ x[1][4][5]+ x[1][5][5]+ x[1][5][5] - y[1][5] >= 0

x[2][1][1]+ x[2][1][1]+ x[2][1][2]+ x[2][2][1]+ x[2][1][3]+ x[2][3][1]+ x[2][1][4]+ x[2][4][1]+ x[2][1][5]+ x[2][5][1] - y[2][1] >= 0

x[2][2][1]+ x[2][1][2]+ x[2][2][2]+ x[2][2][2]+ x[2][2][3]+ x[2][3][2]+ x[2][2][4]+ x[2][4][2]+ x[2][2][5]+ x[2][5][2] - y[2][2] >= 0

x[2][3][1]+ x[2][1][3]+ x[2][3][2]+ x[2][2][3]+ x[2][3][3]+ x[2][3][3]+ x[2][3][4]+ x[2][4][3]+ x[2][3][5]+ x[2][5][3] - y[2][3] >= 0

x[2][4][1]+ x[2][1][4]+ x[2][4][2]+ x[2][2][4]+ x[2][4][3]+ x[2][3][4]+ x[2][4][4]+ x[2][4][4]+ x[2][4][5]+ x[2][5][4] - y[2][4] >= 0

x[2][5][1]+ x[2][1][5]+ x[2][5][2]+ x[2][2][5]+ x[2][5][3]+ x[2][3][5]+ x[2][5][4]+ x[2][4][5]+ x[2][5][5]+ x[2][5][5] - y[2][5] >= 0

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For r=2, V=5 and i=5
I expanded the equation And defined every equation as separate constraint.

Comment: Please add this line as an edit to the question.

Comment: Thank you  @Lorelorelore

Comment: The linear programming solvers in SciPy have a matrix based API. So no summations. You have to populate the LP matrix by code. Indeed this can be cumbersome for some models. You may have a look at a Python tool like Pulp or Pyomo which allows a more algebraic (sums etc.) representation. These tools also support better solvers.

Comment: But i have non-linear constraints also . With this my objective function is also non-linear. In that case what will be the best suggestion according to you?

Comment: Nonlinear constrained solvers in SciPy use a function based API. In a function you can do anything you like. E.g. using sum or numpy.sum. However it does not give you a real algebraic feel. Pyomo comes closer to that. It can do both linear and non-linear models and gives you access to high-quality large-scale (linear and nonlinear) solvers.

Comment: Thank you for help @ErwinKalvelagen. I have tried pyomo . But i am confused between solvers. Can you suggest me any good solver which can solve Non-Linear problems and able to work with binary variables.

Comment: MINLP solvers for Pyomo are readily available (e.g. Bonmin, Couenne)

Comment: I have tried both but Couenne is very time taking solver.

Comment: Well, it is a global solver. So depending on the model, it is supposed to be slow.